# How to style the numbers and currency symbol after dot?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I've used angular **currency** pipe to display numbers after comma.

```
<ion-label class="accordion_balance">{{balance | currency:'KZT':'symbol-narrow':'1.2-2'}}</ion-label>
```

**result:**

[image]

I need to make smaller the numbers and currency symbol after comma, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you have to style the numbers and currency symbol separately. Angular pipe only returns back a string, there's no way to style individual characters within a string.

The good news is that you can chain a customized pipe to split the string into parts. For example, the pipe splits `35 000,00T` into `35 000` and `00T`. Then apply different styles separately:

```
<ion-label class="accordion_balance">
    <ng-container *ngIf="let currencyValues = balance | currency:'KZT':'symbol-narrow':'1.2-2' | yourCustomisedPipe"
        <span class="currency_large_number">{{currencyValues[0]}}</span> <!--35 000,-->
        <span class="currency_small_number">{{currencyValues[1]}}</span> <!--00T-->
    </ng-container>
</ion-label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that with the pipe `currency` in the html.

But there is solution :

You can create your own directive or component which will do the job.

You can use :

```
const money = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'KZT' }).format(35000))
```

And then, you split your `money` to get `35000`, `00` and `₸`

And if you use a component, you can have something like:

```
<span class="money">
   {{unit}}, 
   <span class="digit">{{digit}}</span>
   &nbsp
   <span class="currency">{{currency}}</span>
</span>
```